# Wordpress Send Cart information to php

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, variables

I have a website in wordpress with woocommerce.
I need to get the total price of the items  (items of the cart) in order to send via email with php.
I think 2 options:
-   Save the information in a variable (var) php and then send it via email
-   Get the content of a div which has a defined class and then send it via email 
For example: Information of wordpress
TV Led u$s 300
Smartphone u$s 100
Total: u$s 400.-
I would like to received the information via email.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must to create an array with all the items in the cart. Them use 'for' statement and sum all the prices of each item into the array.

something like this:

```
    $items=  [
    "milk" => 150,
    "juice" => 70,
    "Orange" => 90
];
    $total = 0;
    foreach($items as $item){ $total = $total + $item; }
echo $total;
```